# How does polaroid filter work at the atomic level?

Tags: visible-light, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

I know it works by blocking electric or magnetic component of wave while allowing other but what happens at the atomic level , do the atoms absorb the electric component e.g by excitation of electrons ? or do the bonds resonate at frequency of electric component of wave ?

Comment: Nice question. It is the key to the understanding of deflection on edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polaroid filter works at the molecular or supra-molecular level.  Tiny, but long and thin crystals are oriented in a plastic matrix so that they all point in the same direction. Electrons can move farther and more easily in the long direction.  Individual atoms are not responsible for the polarization effects of a polaroid filter.  Note that wire grid polarizers are very effective, and they employ very conductive paths (often aluminum or gold) on the order of a hundred nanometers wide but with lengths on the order of inches.

Comment: So you mean since electrons can move in path made by crystals , The electric field forces them to move in that path ? and that's how electric field gets used up ?

Comment: Not exactly, but something like that.  You can think of the crystals as being electrically conductive, but unless two crystals are joined at the ends, electrons are unlikely to move between the crystals.